# How to use settings in Visual C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, settings

I have been a VB.net developer for a long time and changed recently to C#.
When I was using VB.net, to call user settings, I just need to create a new setting using the designer and then call it from code with the My namespace.
Here's the code
`My.settings.anysetting`
I can change or get data from it.
However in C# the My keyword doesn't work, so what can I do to call settings??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Settings` are stored under the `Application` folder and as such, use that as their namespace.

```
int myInt = Properties.Settings.Default.myVariable;
Properties.Settings.Default.myVariable = 12;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

[Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx)

Comment: I didn't thought it'll be that easy, I 'll try :p

Comment: Settings in C# are very easy and nice, only part I don't like is the .config file with comes with your executable. A curious user might think that is where the settings are stored, but it's not, they are the defaults.

Comment: Are you sure that the folder is `Application`?  It looks like `Properties` is the namespace here (and in my actual application).

Answer (score 1):

Kinda like this:

```
this.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.myColor;
```

Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397759(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
// Retrieving connection string from Web.config.
String connStringMSQL = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["andi_msql"].ToString();
```

In my case this was for my connectionStrings setting but depending on what node your setting is in you can change this accordingly.

Hope this helps

Comment: appologies thing i misunderstood the question

Comment: The question mentions nothing about ASP.Net.

Comment: You must not be familiar with write-write conflicts. It's nothing personal.