# How to use properties.settings.default in <script> _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

We are trying to use the general properties.settings in our cshtml layout page.
The var setting is in the  tag (jQuery)

We are able to reach the `properties.settings.default.OurSetting` in our controller.

We looked at a few questions on SO but they only gave examples to reach it in the controller.

ex: [Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-application)

[How to use settings in Visual C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650555/how-to-use-settings-in-visual-c-sharp)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C

So we are tried to do

```
var setting = '@(MyProjectName.Properties.Settings.Default.OurSetting)'
```

But that says the name Properties does not exist in the current context.

**EDIT**

We used the appSettings from the web.config first but because we want to be able to change the setting w/o reloading the app.

Comment: You'll have to either add the using for the namespace the settings are residing in (or add it to the line).

Comment: Can you show us an example, cause we already did that, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change Access Modifier of the Settings.Designer from internal to public.

Comment: Don't change it in Settings.Designer.cs, change it in the Settings Designer, unless you want the designer to overwrite your change.

Comment: @jrummell both will have same effect. Can you tell me the difference between doing that in designer & designer.cs.

Comment: Indeed @jrummell We also found that out after the response of Kapil.

In a way it did give us the response my co-worker made a small mistake.

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal - change it in the Settings Designer UI (not code) by double clicking Settings.settings. The designer will recreate the file each time you change anything in the designer, so any of your changes made to the .designer.cs file will be lost.

Comment: Do the settings always reload to their default values? Even when you change them?

Comment: No, it is case when we make changes in the Settings.Designer.cs auto-generated file instead of Settings.Designer.

Comment: Sorry I meant that they always reload after an application restart. Is there anyway to even change the default?