# how to access the project properties in a .cshtml razor file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

is it possible to Access my Project Properties within the .cshtml Razor file?
I need something like this:

```
@if (myProject.Properties.Settings.Default.foo) {...}
```

while foo is a `boolean`

I get the error that because of a security reason it is not possible.

Comment: How about setting that property in the ViewBag (in the Controller) and calling it from there?

Comment: Good idea, will try it

Comment: but the problem is, that this is my _Layout page, where do I have the Viewbag for it? I will not set it in every single controller that I have

Comment: Use a BaseController and set it there, or, as lavrik says, use the web.config for your settings and reference from there :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't really be calling `ConfigurationManager` directly from your view. Views should be 'dumb' in MVC, ie not have any knowledge of the data structure or back-end, and by calling `ConfigurationManager` directly your view knows too much about how your settings are stored. If you changed your settings to use a different store (ie a database) then you'd have to change your view.

So, you should grab that value elsewhere and pass it to your view so your view just takes care of rendering it and that's it. You probably have 2 options:

1. Add something into the ViewBag and grab it in the view
2. Render an action from a common controller that passes a strongly typed ViewModel to a partial view.

I'd discourage option 1 because in general it is good to avoid the `ViewBag` because it isn't strongly typed ([Is using ViewBag in MVC bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766062/is-using-viewbag-in-mvc-bad)). Also, to do this you'd either have to inherit from a `BaseController` for every controller which can be a pain, or create a global action filter that overrides `ActionExecuted` and stuffs something in the `ViewBag` there.

Option 2 is probably better. I'd create a common controller something like:

```
public class CommonController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ViewResult Settings()
    {
        // Get some config settings etc here and make a view model
        var model = new SettingsModel { Foo = myProject.Properties.Settings.Default.foo };

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then in your layout file you can call:

```
@Html.Action("Settings", new { controller = "Common" })
```

Which renders a strongly-typed partial view (~/Views/Common/Settings.cshtml) which looks like:

```
@model YourProject.Models.SettingsModel

@if(Model.Foo)
{
    // So something
}
```

That way you are still using a strongly typed model and view, your layout view stays clean and simple and your partial view remains 'dumb'

Comment: what if this is needed in the _Layout view?

Comment: This still works - just call the action from your layout view and it will be included

Answer (score 0):

The app settings are stored in the web.config file as

```
<applicationSettings>
 <YourProject.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="Setting" serializeAs="String">
    <value>asdqwe</value>
  </setting>
```

so you can try use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings dictionary like

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting"]
```

Comment: Then I get a error that the "ConfigurationManager" is not available in this context

Comment: You should read configurationmanager in controller because its not the job of layout page to do this. The sole purpose of layout page is to render the values that are given to it. Providing values to view is the responsibility of controller.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395118/how-to-use-properties-settings-default-in-script-layout-cshtml). And ConfigurationManager should be avalilable on the views.

Comment: use @using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager in Page(.cshtml)