# How to create a BaseController with a ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to do the following:
I have some Controllers ready and running, but now I want to create a `BaseController`.
Each of my `Controllers` should inherit from it like this:

```
public class MySecondController : BaseController
```

thats already running so far. **Now the Problem:**

I want to add a `ViewBag` into this base controller. This `ViewBag` should be accessable from every view which is called in my controllers.

How to realise this?

Comment: I've answered your other question which explains how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034728/how-to-access-the-project-properties-in-a-cshtml-razor-file

Comment: **See Also**: [Set ViewBag property in the constructor of a ASP.NET MVC Core controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40330391/1366033)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can override [OnActionExecuting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx) method in the overridden method you can data to [`ViewBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx) dictionary.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewBag.someThing = "someThing"; //Add whatever
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Updated for .net Core 2019:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewBag.someThing = "someThing"; //Add whatever
        ViewData["someThingElse"] = "this works too";
        TempData["anotherThing"] = "as does this";
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do u consume it