# How to instantiate a user profile object once per request, in ASP.NET MVC, and then reuse in all code for that request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET4.5, SQL Server 2008.

I have a "User" class which contains details about the current user ie Organisation details.

At present I instantiate a new user object on each view or action where needed which makes calls to the db, and of course this is wasteful, as I could instantiate this object when the request is first made. I could then reuse the object throughout the request processing, to include action and view processing.

What would be the correct approach to do this. I had thought of loading the object into a session, but I am trying to avoid the use of these. Also I had an idea of using a static class that checks for the present of the instantiated object, and creates it is absent, then gets the relevant properties. Here is some possible code to illustrate my thinking:

```
    public static class stCurrentUser
    {
      public static CurrentUser GetUserDetails()
      {
        CurrentUser myUser = (CurrentUser)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"];
        if (myUser == null)
        {
            myUser = new CurrentUser();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = myUser;
            return myUser;

        }
        else
        {
            return myUser;
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your Session[] approach/example would result in a very different lifetime for the data. You do want it per request, right?

Comment: Yes @HenkHolterman, I do.... so I guess session will not be my ideal solution, but something else ??

Comment: Session was the first to come to mind, and I could get something working....

Comment: I think its always good to get the CurrentUser fresh, why to persist in session or any other way as its very important info that controls all the access functionality then why to compromise. You can set it in base controller as property and pass on that to other methods whenever required. If its null create new though it should never be static.

Comment: @GirishSakhare, thanks for this. Interesting thought. I had a similar thought to using the base controller. How would you propose passing this object to the View? Could you set a ViewBag in the Base Controller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035296/how-to-create-a-basecontroller-with-a-viewbag

Comment: @GirishSakhare, Thanks for this. Most useful. The solution I have adopted at present is to use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["Something"] which works well. How would your approach compare?