# How to properly save application data for later use

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok, so I am working on a c# windows forms application and it uses different types of structures that hold data and display to the user.  I want to use a saveDialogBox to allow the user to save the information(i.e configuration, state).  The only way I can think to do this is to make a routine that goes through the structures and write the corresponding elements to a text file.  Upon loading this routine would be used to load the data back.

This is of course a dumb way to do it I'll admit.  Anything I've done in school was only writing to text files.  Is there other ways to make some formatted file to save and load from?

I've been looking at serialization to save objects to files.  I am not too sure how all this works though. help.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what types of data you're wanting to save? The optimal answer depends on what specifically you're wanting to persist.

Comment: As Jacob says , it depends. However, restrain yourself from calling it dumb. There are perfectly valid situations for saving to a (text) file.

Comment: we do something currently like that and we store the settings in a Database or to a `XML File`

Comment: Have you considered creating your own Settings class that will store all settings you need instead of putting them in each structure? (Again this really depends on your application/data). In addition to the XML/Binary serializer you can define your own serialization with the DataContract serializer.

Comment: @KenWhite check the name of the poster of the comment you're responding to.

Comment: "configuration, state" is not very specific. Precisely what type of data are you needing to store, and how large is it? If you edit your question to be more specific about what you want to store, it will make it much more likely you get a useful answer. Being vague typically causes questions to be closed or downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to save your application setting .. I think these links will help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx
http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/AppSettings.aspx

and

[How to use settings in Visual C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650555/how-to-use-settings-in-visual-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1):

My 'Old School' way of doing this has always been to save settings during the program execution to a database (providing that you take the time to ensure you're not hammering the database with updates / inserts).

If my application needs to be more efficient AND I need to easily be able to recall the saved settings I serialize to XML using System.Xml.Serialization (from memory). XML serialization is human readable which is helpful (but not the most efficient in terms of processing time).

If I need even more efficiency you can go the whole way and serialize to binary.

I'd suggest reading / understanding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Vstudio/ms233843.aspx in it's entirety before coming back here. I'd say once you read this you'll be far better equipped to make a decision on which way you want to take your application.

In my experience there aren't that many DUMB ways to solve problems however there is almost always a better way to solve them given enough time and research.