# appending to a string array in C#

Tags: c#

```
    string Input = "";
    string[] Words = { "elephant", "lion" };
    string[] Clues = { "Has trunk?", "Is gray?", "Is yellow?", "Has mane?"};
```

.........

```
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add you own animal? y/n ? \n");
        Input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Input == "Y" || Input == "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an animal name: \n");
            //Array.Resize(ref Words, Words.Length + 1);
            Input = Console.ReadLine();
            Words[Words.Length] = Input;


            Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 clues \n");
            for (int i = 1; i <=2 ; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Clue" + i + ":");
                Clues[Clues.Length] = Console.ReadLine();

            }

        }
```

This is the standard guess the animal game..
I am getting an **`index out of bounds`** at line `Words[Words.Length] = Input;`.. the new animal  and clues entered also needs to be available the next time i play the game..

Comment: Use `List<string>` (and `VariableName.Add`) rather than an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly save application data for later use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156842/how-to-properly-save-application-data-for-later-use)

Comment: Also, arrays in C# are 0-based, not 1-based. So `for (int i = 1; i <=2 ; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `List<string>` instead of `Array`. Your code throw exception because you are trying to add element to an Array in outranged index. I modified your code like this;

```
        string Input = "";
        var Words = new List<string> { "elephant", "lion" };
        var Clues = new List<string> { "Has trunk?", "Is gray?", "Is yellow?", "Has mane?" };
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add you own animal? y/n ? \n");
        Input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Input == "Y" || Input == "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an animal name: \n");
            //Array.Resize(ref Words, Words.Length + 1);
            Input = Console.ReadLine();
            Words.Add(Input);


            Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 clues \n");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Clue" + i + ":");
                var clueInput = Console.ReadLine();
                Clues.Add(clueInput);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead `string []` use `List<T>` from *System.Collections.Generic*

And you can use [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method to add new value like this.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter an animal name: \n");
Input = Console.ReadLine();
Words.Add(Input);
```

And if want an array at the end, you can use `ToArray` method. Like this.

```
Words.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a string to a finite array such as the one you have declared causes this *additional* item to be beyond the bounds of this array, ie. you are squeezing more things into a space that cannot hold that amount. Once created (at compilation) this size is fixed and can't be changed until next time.

I think what you are looking for are lists `List<string>` that use `list.Add()` to easily manipulate content dynamically during runtime.

Let me know if that answers your question or if you require more details.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use List rather Array.

```
     string Input = "";
    List<string> Words = new List<string>(){ "elephant", "lion" };
    List<string>  Clues =new List<string>() { "Has trunk?", "Is gray?", "Is yellow?", "Has mane?"};

 Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add you own animal? y/n ? \n");
    Input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (Input.toLower() == "y")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an animal name: \n");
        //Array.Resize(ref Words, Words.Length + 1);
        Input = Console.ReadLine();
        Words.Add(Input);


        Console.WriteLine("Enter 2 clues \n");
        for (int i = 1; i <=2 ; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clue" + i + ":");
            Clues.Add(Console.ReadLine());

        }

    }
```

please follow this.

Answer (score 0):

```
`Console.WriteLine("Enter an animal name: \n");
//Hear Words length is 2 and Data (0 = elephant,1 = lion)
Array.Resize(ref Words, Words.Length + 1);
//Hear Words length is 3 and Data (0 = elephant,1 = lion,2 = null)
Input = Console.ReadLine();
//if you write Words[Words.Length] means you tried to access 3 index which is not available.
//You should write this.
Words[Words.Length - 1] = Input;`
```